# QEMU -hda file.img is /dev/sda in Linux?

Tags: linux, qemu

I tried passing `-hda file.img` to QEMU command line as root device, but it seems the booted Linux kernel shows it as `/dev/sda` instead of `/dev/hda`. Why does this different happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-hda` option emulates a PATA disk. At around 2006, Linux switched to [a different kind of PATA drivers](https://lwn.net/Articles/198344/) – the new ones were written using LibATA to make the disks appear as if they were SCSI devices, and therefore use `sd` names instead of `hd`.

(In fact, the "old style" IDE drivers were completely removed from Linux just this week and LibATA is the only method that remains.)